# How to handle multiple user controls on same page - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, user-controls, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a situation that needs two same user controls in a page. User control needs to communicate with the page and vice-versa, so I used events to do that. However, when I fire an event on the page to UC it goes and hit both objects causing twice execution of my functions. This UC's are bind to a ViewModel as well but those were not disposing of when I exit the page. So when the user comes back to the same page and executes something it will hit all the remaining objects in the memory. (Because events did not unbind)

I think I did not use the UC the correct way. Please let me know how to properly communicate from page to UC and UC to page, and how to use the same UC multiple times on the same page.

This is a UWP app targeting Windows 10 (10240).

Thank you very much for your time. Cheers!

My user control constructor does the binding of the events to the page.

```
 public CommentsUserControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            AgendaPage.PaperCommentsInitializeEvt += (PaperCommentsInitializeEvt);
            AgendaPage.MeetingCommentsInitializeEvt += (MeetingCommentsInitializeEvt);
            AgendaPage.ClearDisplayCommentsEvt += (ClearDisplayCommentsEvt);
}
```

When you navigate to another page and come back these events hit 4 times since in the beginning 2 user controls were initialized.

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what it does

Comment: @MartinZikmund hi, I’ll post it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone.
My solution was to implement an **Unload** method of the Usercontrol and add the unbind code for my events.

```
AgendaPage.PaperCommentsInitializeEvt -= (PaperCommentsInitializeEvt);
AgendaPage.MeetingCommentsInitializeEvt -= (MeetingCommentsInitializeEvt);
AgendaPage.ClearDisplayCommentsEvt -= (ClearDisplayCommentsEvt);
```